# How to get row data on right click event in flextable of GWT?

Tags: gwt

In below code, docName1 will have `object HTMLDivElement` as value.
I want the row data.

```
versionTable.sinkEvents(Event.ONCONTEXTMENU);
versionTable.addHandler(new ContextMenuHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
        event.getNativeEvent().preventDefault();
        event.getNativeEvent().stopPropagation();
        final int x=event.getNativeEvent().getClientX();
        final int y=event.getNativeEvent().getClientY();

        String docName1=event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().toString();
        Window.alert(docName1);
    }
}
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

If by the "row data" you mean text content of the table cell, than you should use `Element.getInnerText()`:

```java
public void onContextMenu(ContextMenuEvent event) {
    ...    
    Element el = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();
    String docName1 = el.getInnerText();
    Window.alert(docName1);
}
```

But, you have to be shure, that event target is a correct DOM element, that contains the "row data".